# How do I prove that the following sum converges?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

I have the following problem:

> Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of i.i.d. exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda>0$. I need to show that $\forall \epsilon >0$ $$\sum_n \Bbb{P}\left(\frac{X_n}{log(n)}>\epsilon +\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)<\infty$$

My Idea was the following. Define $\Lambda_n=\left\{\frac{X_n}{log(n)}>\epsilon +\frac{1}{\lambda}\right\}=\left\{X_n\leq \log(n)\left(\epsilon +\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)\right\}^c$. Now I thought that for a fixed $n$ we have $$\Bbb{P}(\Lambda_n)=1-\Bbb{P}\left(\left\{X_n\leq \log(n)\left(\epsilon +\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)\right\}\right)=1-\int_{-\infty}^{\log(n)\left(\epsilon +\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$$

But somehow I get in trouble with this $-\infty$ since $\lambda >0$. So I wanted to ask, what did I oversee or is everything wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly calculate.

You are actually making the mistake in the pdf of the exponential random variable.

If $X\sim \exp(\lambda) $ then the pdf $f(x)$ is given by:-

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\lambda e^{-\lambda x},\,x\geq 0\\0\,\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$

$$P\left(\frac{X_n}{\ln(n)}>\epsilon +\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)=P(X_{n}>\ln(n)(\epsilon+\frac{1}{\lambda}))=\\\int_{\ln(n)(\epsilon+\frac{1}{\lambda})}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=\exp\Big(-\lambda\ln(n)\Big(\epsilon+\frac{1}{\lambda}\Big)\Big)$$

$$=\exp\Big(\ln\Big(\frac{1}{n^{(\epsilon+\frac{1}{\lambda})}}\Big)\Big)$$

$$=\frac{1}{n^{\lambda(\epsilon+\frac{1}{\lambda})}}=\frac{1}{n^{\lambda\epsilon+1}}$$.

Now $\sum\frac{1}{n^{p}}$ converges if $p>1$ which it is in this case so you are done.

Comment: Sorry I don't see why we have $P(X_{n}>\ln(n)(\epsilon+\frac{1}{\lambda}))=\int_{\\ln(n)(\epsilon+\frac{1}{\lambda})}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx$

Comment: could you maybe explain this a bit more, because I only know a formula for $\Bbb{P}(X\leq a)$

Comment: You are making a mistake in the pdf.

Comment: ah yes I see thanks! I didn't see that, so my integral works but starts from $0$. then everything is correct right?

Comment: Exactly. Also you can directly use the cdf and get the value instead of integrating

Comment: perfect thanks!